# Need help moving animations using pygame

Tags: python, animation, pygame

```
import pygame,sys
 
FPS = 60
LEVEL = []
BACKGROUND_COLOR = ("black")
WIDTH,HEIGHT = 1250,490
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT)) #window
pygame.display.set_caption("Pac-Man")
 
BLOCK_SIZE = 32



char_to_image = {
    '.': 'dot.png',
    '=': 'wall.png',
    '*': 'power.png',
}



class Pacman(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.is_animating = False
        self.sprites = []
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('pacman_c.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load('pacman_o.png'))
        self.curr = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.curr]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = [x,y]

    def update(self):
        
        if self.is_animating == True:
            self.curr += 0.05
            if self.curr >= len(self.sprites):    
                self.is_animating = False
                self.curr = 0
            self.image = self.sprites[int(self.curr)]
            

    def animate(self):
        self.is_animating = True

    def movement(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key == pygame.K_w:
            print("w")
            self.y -= 32
        elif key == pygame.K_s:
            print("s")
            self.Y += 32
        elif key == pygame.K_a:
            print("a")
            self.x -= 32
        elif key == pygame.K_d:
            print("d")
            self.x += 32


def loadMap(number): #load in the text file into the array LEVEL 
    file = "map-%s.txt" % number
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            row = []
            for char in line.strip():
                if char != " ":
                    screen_char = pygame.image.load(char_to_image[char])
                    row.append(screen_char)
                else:
                    row.append(0)
            LEVEL.append(row)
 
    for row in LEVEL:
        for char in row:
            print(char)
    
def draw(number): # trying to use blit to take the char array and change it to string
    x = y = 0
    for row in LEVEL:
        for char in row:
            if char != 0:
                screen.blit(char, (x,y))
            x += 32
        x = 0
        y += 32
 
    pygame.display.update()
 
def main():
 
    loadMap(1) # change the number to change the map
    pman_X,pman_Y = 32,32*13
    moving_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    pacman = Pacman(pman_X,pman_Y)
    moving_sprites.add(pacman)
    
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    play = True

    while play:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            clock.tick(FPS)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                play = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                pacman.movement()
                pacman.animate()
        
        draw(1)
        moving_sprites.draw(screen)
        moving_sprites.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
    
    
    pygame.quit()
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code is picking up on the key presses but it's not updating the location of the sprite,  the animations themselves don't reset after the frame i.e when Pac-Man opens his mouth the old frame is still showing up underneath the new frame. Any help would be appreciated. Below I've attached a GitHub link to the project and assets used. (https://github.com/rob-roibu/Pac-man)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `.rect` attribute after moving:

```py
class Pacman(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def movement(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key == pygame.K_w:
            print("w")
            self.y -= 32
        elif key == pygame.K_s:
            print("s")
            self.Y += 32
        elif key == pygame.K_a:
            print("a")
            self.x -= 32
        elif key == pygame.K_d:
            print("d")
            self.x += 32

        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y) # <-- this is missing
```

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw).

---

You need to clear the display in ever frame:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while play:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            clock.tick(FPS)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                play = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                pacman.movement()
                pacman.animate()
        
        screen.fill(0) # <--- this is missing

        draw(1)
        moving_sprites.draw(screen)
        moving_sprites.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)